# Passing Pointer by Reference not working as intended

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, binary-search-tree

I was writing code to delete a node from a BST recursively mainly as a study exercise to implement recurion and to verify my understanding of certain coding elements I have used. In this case the issue seems to be with passing the pointer to my BST node by reference.

A psrt of my BST code is as follows. (This is not code for something I would implement or use. Just an exercise. I chose BST as an example to implement some things I wanted to try out in the language)

Header -

```
//BST.h
class TNode
{
public:
    TNode():data(0), left(0), right(0) {}
    int data;
    TNode* left;
    TNode* right;
};

class BST
{
private:
    TNode* Head;

public:
    BST();

    void InsertData(int data);
    void InsertNode(TNode* node);
    void DeleteData(int data);

private:
    void InsertDataPrivate(int data, TNode* &root); 
    void InsertNodePrivate(TNode* node, TNode* &root);
    void DeleteDataPrivate(int data, TNode* &root);
};
```

CPP -

```
//BST.cpp
#include "BST.h"

BST::BST(): Head(0)
{

}

void BST::InsertData(int data)
{
    InsertDataPrivate(data, Head);
}

void BST::InsertNode(TNode* node)
{
    InsertNodePrivate(node, Head);
}

void BST::DeleteData(int data)
{
    DeleteDataPrivate(data, Head);
}


void BST::InsertDataPrivate(int data, TNode* &root) 
{
    if(root == 0)
    {
        root = new TNode();
        root->data = data;
    }
    else if(data < root->data) InsertDataPrivate(data, root->left);
    else if(data > root->data) InsertDataPrivate(data, root->right); 
}

void BST::InsertNodePrivate(TNode* node, TNode* &root) 
{
    if(root == 0) // Deep Copy
    {
        root = new TNode();
        root->data = node->data;
    }

    else if(node->data < root->data) InsertNodePrivate(node, root->left);
    else if(node->data > root->data) InsertNodePrivate(node, root->right); 
}

void BST::DeleteDataPrivate(int data, TNode* &root)
{
    if( 0 == root ) return;

    if( root->data == data )
    {
        if(0 == root->left && 0 == root->right)
        {
            delete root;
            root = 0;
        }
        else if(0 == root->left)
        {
            TNode* current = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete current;
            current = 0;
        }
        else if(0 == root->right)
        {
            TNode* current = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete current;
            current = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            TNode* biggestOnLeft = root->left;
            TNode* smallestOnRight = root->right;
            int i = 0;
            while (biggestOnLeft->right) // check if left subtree is longer than right subtree
            {
                biggestOnLeft = biggestOnLeft->right;
                --i;
            }
            while (smallestOnRight->left)
            {
                smallestOnRight = smallestOnRight->left;
                ++i;
            }
            if(i < 0) // left subtree is longer than right subtree
            {
                root->data = biggestOnLeft->data;
                DeleteDataPrivate(biggestOnLeft->data, biggestOnLeft);
            }
            else // right subtree is longer than or equal in size to left subtree
            {
                root->data = smallestOnRight->data;
                DeleteDataPrivate(smallestOnRight->data, smallestOnRight);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(data < root->data && 0 !=root->left)
    {
        DeleteDataPrivate(data, root->left);
    }
    else if(data > root->data && 0 !=root->right)
    {
        DeleteDataPrivate(data, root->right);
    }
}
```

and my test code is as follows -

```
//TestMain.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BST.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BST bst;

    bst.InsertData(32);
    bst.InsertData(46);
    bst.InsertData(3463);
    bst.InsertData(32);
    bst.InsertData(856);
    bst.InsertData(8098);
    bst.InsertData(345);
    bst.InsertData(234554);
    bst.InsertData(77);
    bst.InsertData(9);
    bst.InsertData(15);
    bst.InsertData(390);
    bst.InsertData(350);
    bst.InsertData(400);
    bst.InsertData(76);
    bst.InsertData(78);
    bst.InsertData(355);
    bst.DeleteData(77);

    return 0;
}
```

In the last step where I say `bst.DeleteData(77);` I have a problem. The node with '77' gets deleted alright and gets replaced by '78' in a fashion you delete a node with two children from a BST. However after deleting the node that had '78' before deletion of the parent node that had '77' still points to a non-null location.

I am calling my private function `DeleteDataPrivate(int data, TNode* &root);` which sets the TNode pointer to NULL after deleting it. Also I am passing the pointer-by-reference in the function so that the NULL value gets assigned to the deleted node pointer as the recursion stack unfolds back. This does not happen. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Chinmay

**UPDATE**

As per Dan's comment below the issue was with values being passed to local variables which made copies of my pointers and were not assigned back to anything. I have modified my function to account for this by using a pointer-to-pointer to so that the value of TNode pointer returned by the unwinding recursion is stored at the correct location in memory and not in some copy of TNode pointer.

The modified function is as follows

```
void BST::DeleteDataPrivate(int data, TNode* &root)
{
    if( 0 == root ) return;

    if( root->data == data )
    {
        if(0 == root->left && 0 == root->right)
        {
            delete root;
            root = 0;
        }
        else if(0 == root->left)
        {
            TNode* current = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete current;
            current = 0;
        }
        else if(0 == root->right)
        {
            TNode* current = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete current;
            current = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            TNode* biggestOnLeft = root->left;
            TNode* smallestOnRight = root->right;
            int i = 0;
            while (biggestOnLeft->right) // check if left subtree is longer than right subtree
            {
                biggestOnLeft = biggestOnLeft->right;
                --i;
            }
            while (smallestOnRight->left)
            {
                smallestOnRight = smallestOnRight->left;
                ++i;
            }
            TNode** locationOfDeletedNode = 0;
            if(i < 0) // left subtree is longer than right subtree
            {

                locationOfDeletedNode = &(root->left);
                while(*locationOfDeletedNode != biggestOnLeft) locationOfDeletedNode = &((*locationOfDeletedNode)->right);
            }
            else // right subtree is longer than or equal in size to left subtree
            {
                locationOfDeletedNode = &(root->right);
                while(*locationOfDeletedNode != smallestOnRight) locationOfDeletedNode = &((*locationOfDeletedNode)->left);

            }
            root->data = (*locationOfDeletedNode)->data;
            DeleteDataPrivate((*locationOfDeletedNode)->data, *locationOfDeletedNode);
        }
    }
    else if(data < root->data && 0 !=root->left)
    {
        DeleteDataPrivate(data, root->left);
    }
    else if(data > root->data && 0 !=root->right)
    {
        DeleteDataPrivate(data, root->right);
    }
}
```

Ofcourse this can be structured better and stuff but my goal here was to learn simple but tricky things here and thanks to Dan and others I have done that here.

Comment: Can you show the method `DeleteDataPrivate()`?

Comment: @noMAD - it is in the BST.cpp.

Comment: damn, this scroll thing gets you at times. Anyways, you got a fix :)

Comment: @DavidHammen I will accept the fix here since it does show me where I am wrong and I understand it now. I was just trying to fix the issue so I could update and close the topic. In the past, I have not accepted the answer when I have not been able to get a convincing solution to a problem. I thought it would be wrong to. I did find all the help useful though and am thankful for that. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call

```
DeleteDataPrivate(biggestOnLeft->data, biggestOnLeft);
```

It just assigns to the local variable `biggestOnLeft`, it does not assign to any object's member.

Because when you do

```
TNode* biggestOnLeft = root->left;
```

It creates a new variable which is a *copy* of `root->left`, not the same thing.

### Fix ideas

You can try starting `biggestOnLeft` and `smallestOnRight` at root, and doing

```
while (biggestOnLeft->right->right)
```

Then you can call

```
DeleteDataPrivate(biggestOnLeft->data, biggestOnLeft->right);
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this, and could have made a typo or something.

Comment: Thank you. But how will starting at root help? Won't I be making a copy of the root pointer instead of the root->left? Also in this case I call `DeleteDataPrivate()` on the node '78' in the end which is a child-less node and so the execution goes into `  if(0 == root->left && 0 == root->right)
  {
   delete root;
   root = 0;
  }` 
Shouldn't that '0' be passed to its parent->right when coming out of recursion?

Comment: I got it now. I made a small change to my solution and will update my post above. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot assign NULL to the pointer by reference TNode because a reference variable cannot be NULL. Please see [C++ pass pointer by reference and assign default value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830064/147333)

Comment: Yes you can, assigning `NULL` to a reference to a pointer is just assigning `NULL` to the pointer the reference is bound to.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I did see that thread but I was not getting any errors. I thought I was assigning NULL value to the TNode pointer whose location was referenced by my 'reference to TNode pointer'. Isnt that what I was doing?